# Present Simple with today

Tags: present-perfect, present-simple

I have a few sentences in the Present Simple with "today". I am going to give my understanding of them.

1. For example, Bob is a guitar teacher. He has a student - Bill. Meanwhile, they don't have a schedule of their lessons. They meet up off and on after having arranged every lesson on the phone. Would it be OK for Bill to say this?

   Bill: "This is Bill. **Do we have a lesson today?**" (Meaning, are we going to have a lesson today?)
2. A similar scenario. Bill wants to enroll in guitar lessons. Today is going to be his first lesson. And he is asked by a friend of his

   Friend: "What are you going to do today after school, Bill?"

   Bill: "I have a guitar lesson today."

   (Is that answer good? Or should it be "I am having a guitar lesson today?)

   Another thing. Am I right to think that his friend may understand that Bill has a guitar lesson regularly on that day of the week? If today was a Sunday then it is possible to infer that Bill has a guitar lesson on Sundays?

   It seems to me that "I have a guitar lesson today" may mean either a) it is a one-off lesson b) a regular lesson depending on context. Is my assumption correct?
3. A conference takes place today at 2 PM. Now it is 9 AM. The conference is a one-off occasion. Is it OK to say "Guys, don't forget we hold a conference today at 2 PM."?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) BILL [to Bob, over the phone]. Do we have a lesson today?

This is correct, kind of. Curiously, if Bill were the teacher and Bob the student, the question would sound a bit odd. But that's a whole different story. A better way of putting it would be "**Are we still on for today?**"

> 2) I have a guitar lesson today.

This is correct as well. Kind of. "I am having a guitar lesson today?" is wrong. That said, "**I have a guitar lesson**" sounds better. The "today" part is implied.

*Would it be reasonable to assume that Bill has a guitar lesson regularly on that day of the week?*

No, it would not.

> 3) A conference is scheduled for 2 PM. It is 9 AM now. The conference is a one-off occasion. Is it OK to say "Guys, don't forget we hold a conference today at 2 PM."

Kind of. A better way of putting it would be "**Guys, don't forget we have a conference at 2.**"